# какой фреймворк python выбрать?

Tags: python, django, flask

Пишу приложение для торговли на бирже

Фронт - React

Бэкенд - python

Не могу определиться какой фреймворк python выбрать.

Задача бэкенда принимать запрос от фронта, делать запрос на стороннее API и возвращать его ответ на фронт. Также на бэкенде должен рабоатать модуль аналитки, который делает опреации с этими данными и сам посылает запросы на стороннее API. Есть вероятность появления PWA.

Предполагается большая нагрузка и скорость работы критична для приложения.
Мне почти не нужны модели и админка. Выбираю между django, flask, FastApi, но если есть другие варианты, буду рад услышать. Что подскажете? Интересует самое простое решения данных задач

изначально хотел взять django, но он избыточен и как я понял из прочтения статей не очень хорош в асинхронности

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Голосую за закрытие данного вопроса из-за нехватки входных данных и невозможности дать объективный ответ. Выбор должен основываться на функционале, который реализуется, на ресурах и времени на разработку. Каждый из перечисленных фреймворков выполняет поставленные задачи.

Comment: Для учебного проекта - любой. Если смотреть с перспективой применения на будущей работе: сейчас наиболее распространен DRF, реже используется Flask, очень редко FastAPI (т.к. появился относительно недавно - в 2019 г.) Субъективно - FastAPI выглядит довольно перспективно, есть вероятность, что со временем догонит и перегонит Flask по частоте использования.